# What’s the definition of iterated covariant derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry

I’m confused by Arthur Besse’s definition of iterated covariant derivative on p. 25 of his book “Einstein Manifolds". He writes:

> **1.17** Let $\nabla$ be a linear connection on a vector bundle $E$ over $M$. For any section $s$ in $\mathcal E$, $\nabla s$ is a section of $T^*M\otimes E$. Now let $D$ be a linear connection on $M$. Then $D$ and $\nabla$ induce a linear connection (that we still denote by $\nabla$) on $T^*M\otimes E$, so we may define $\nabla(\nabla s)$ and denote it by $\nabla^2 s$. It is the section of $T^{(2,0)}M\otimes E$ defined by
> $$(\nabla^2 s)_{X,Y} = \nabla_X(\nabla_Ys)-\nabla_{(D_XY)}s$$

Here, I’m first perplexed because Besse says that he is denoting $\nabla(\nabla s)$ by $\nabla^2 s$ and then goes on to define $(\nabla^2)_{X,Y} s$ as $\nabla_X(\nabla_Y s)$ minus some other term. Have I missed something here, or did I find a minor mistake in his writing? In any case, he continues

> Now, using an obvious induction we may define the *iterated covariant derivative* $\nabla^p s$ as the section of $T^{(p,0)} M \otimes E$ such that
> $$(\nabla^ps)_{X_1,…,X_p} = (\nabla_{X_1}(\nabla^{p-1}s))_{X_2,…,X_p}\tag{\star}$$

To be clear, how does this definition work out for $p=3$, say $(\nabla^3s)_{X,Y,Z}$? Is it
\begin{align}(\nabla^3s)_{X,Y,Z} &= \nabla_X(\color{red}{\nabla_Y(\nabla_Z s)} \color{blue}{- \nabla_{(D_YZ)}s}) \\
&= \color{red}{\nabla_X(\nabla_Y(\nabla_Z s)) - \nabla_{(D_XY)}(\nabla_Z s) \boxed{-\nabla_Y(\nabla_{(D_XZ)}s)}} \color{blue}{- \nabla_X(\nabla_{D_YZ}s) + \nabla_{D_XD_YZ}s}\end{align}
or shouldn’t the red boxed term be there?

By the way, shouldn’t the RHS of equation $(\star)$ contain the subscript $X_2,…,X_p$ before the closure of the last parenthesis, as in $(\nabla_{X_1}(\nabla^{p-1}s)_{X_2,…,X_p})$, or, even better, $(\nabla_{X_1}((\nabla^{p-1}s)_{X_2,…,X_p}))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $T$ a vector valued $(0,2)$-tensor, we have
$$
\nabla T(X,Y,Z) = \nabla_X(T(Y,Z)) - T(\nabla_XY,Z) - T(Y,\nabla_XZ).
$$
If $T = \nabla^2s$, note that
$
\nabla^2s(Y,Z) = \nabla_Y(\nabla_Zs) - \nabla_{\nabla_YZ}s,
$
so that
\begin{align}
\nabla^3s(X,Y,Z)
&= \nabla_X(\nabla^2s(Y,Z)) - \nabla^2s(\nabla_XY,Z) - \nabla^2s(Y,\nabla_XZ)\\
&= \nabla_X\left(\nabla_Y(\nabla_Zs) - \nabla_{\nabla_YZ}s\right) \\
&\quad - \nabla_{\nabla_XY}(\nabla_Zs) + \nabla_{(\nabla_{\nabla_XY}Z)}s \\
&\quad - \nabla_Y(\nabla_{\nabla_XZ}s) + \nabla_{(\nabla_Y(\nabla_XZ))}s \\
&= \nabla_X(\nabla_Y(\nabla_Zs)) \\
&\quad -\nabla_X(\nabla_{\nabla_YZ}s) - \nabla_{\nabla_XY}(\nabla_Zs) - \nabla_Y(\nabla_{\nabla_XZ}s) \\
&\quad + \nabla_{(\nabla_{\nabla_XY}Z)}s + \nabla_{(\nabla_Y(\nabla_XZ))}s.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is $\nabla T(X,Y,Z) = \nabla_X(T(Y,Z)) - T(\nabla_XY,Z) - T(Y,\nabla_XZ)$? Does it follow from $\nabla_a T_{bc} = \partial_a T_{bc} - \Gamma_{ab}^d T_{dc} - \Gamma_{ac}^dT_{bd}$? It seems slightly different...

Comment: $\nabla T(X,Y,Z) = \nabla_X(T(Y,Z)) - T(\nabla_XY,Z) - T(Y,\nabla_XZ)$ is (also) true if instead of the covariant derivative we have the Lie derivative, right?

Comment: This is the so-called Leibniz rule. It applies to all "derivation"-like objects (and often serves as part of their definition)